# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oscar.apps.dashboard.partnersoscar' in Django Oscar

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am setting up Oscar Django and getting the following error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oscar.apps.dashboard.partnersoscar' in Django Oscar. I have tries searching for the module but cannot find it anywhere.
I have followed all instructions from the docs of django-oscar and my settings.py file is exactly same as it said in the docs.

This is my **settings.py** file

```
import os
from oscar.defaults import *

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i!cxu8iy=vavs4+4om))13vpm455f0$0!rs)e%btew%q+y#mdo'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'oscar',
    'oscar.apps.analytics',
    'oscar.apps.checkout',
    'oscar.apps.address',
    'oscar.apps.shipping',
    'oscar.apps.catalogue',
    'oscar.apps.catalogue.reviews',
    'oscar.apps.partner',
    'oscar.apps.basket',
    'oscar.apps.payment',
    'oscar.apps.offer',
    'oscar.apps.order',
    'oscar.apps.customer',
    'oscar.apps.search',
    'oscar.apps.voucher',
    'oscar.apps.wishlists',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.reports',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.users',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.orders',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.offers',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.partners'
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.pages',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.ranges',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.reviews',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.vouchers',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.communications',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.shipping',
    #3rd-party apps that oscar depends on
    'widget_tweaks',
    'haystack',
    'treebeard',
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'django_tables2',

]
SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'frobshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'frobshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: You are missing a comma after `'oscar.apps.dashboard.partners'` in your list of installed apps, which means the string gets concatenated with the string on the next line.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was very irresponsible of me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your settings are correct in your Django project. Follow these instructions. [Django-Oscar settings](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/internals/getting_started.html#django-settings)

If you still are getting the error please post the code in your **settings.py**

Comment: I have followed all instructions from the Django-oscar docs. I have also posted the settings.py code here. Thanks for the help.